# What is the checkrq algorithm (used by rsync)?

Tags: algorithm, rsync

What is the "checkrq" algorithm used by rsync? I keep seeing it when looking up explanations of how rsync works (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17768678/how-exactly-does-rsync-work-is-it-smart-enough-not-to-transfer-anything-if-your)), but can't find any explanation of what checkrq itself is. Is it similar to a [Merkle tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle_tree)?

Answer (score 3):

There is no "checkrq" algorithm. It is presumably a mistranscription by the (presumably online, e.g. https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) manual page you're using.

Source: check your locally installed man page.

```
 Rsync finds files that need to be transferred using a "quick check" algorithm (by default) that looks for files that have changed in size or in last-modified time.
```

So it basically looks for filesystem attributes (size, modification time) to know if it needs to transfer the file. If your particular deployment scenario makes it likely that a file will be modified in-place without changing the size or updating the modification time, rsync provides a checksum-based method for detecting files that need to be transferred.

```
-c, --checksum              skip based on checksum, not mod-time & size
```

Comment: Necroposting to share that I just noticed (what everyone else has seen for years...) that lqquick checkrq is actually lq for left quote and rq for right quote so "quick check" - doh!